# Does it hurt to leave a light on in the winter

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have a (north of 60 Parallel) modern well insulated home. I heat both the basement and main floors with a ducted electrical hot air furnace held at 18C. If the basement windows are well covered and I leave a florescent or incandescent light on in basement in the winter when the electric furnace is keeping the home warn  day and night. Have I incremented or augmented my electric bill?

1. Do any of the primary or secondary photons of light bounce about and leave in a frequency/form that would leave easier that that of heat. I.E.(radio XRay)?

Comment: agree with safesphere. during the energy crisis of the early 1970's, the operators of large office buildings tried to save energy by turning all the lights off after the occupants had gone home in the evening. what they found was that their heating bills went slightly, but measurably, up because the lights in the building had been contributing heat to the living spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If your electric heater is a heat pump or ground heat pump, then it is more efficient than the bulbs. Otherwise the heater efficiency is the same as the bulbs (100%) and leaving the bulbs on would have the same effect as deflecting a bit of warm air from the heater to the basement (assuming the heater and lighting are on the same meater or billed at the same rate by your utility company).

On your second question, bulb don't produce anyting, other than infrared or light, in the amounts enough to affect your bill. No difference with the curtains closed.